# Parse textarea and display average via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been searching and haven't found any way to do this in JavaScript or if there is a better way.

My form has a text area field that specific string is entered such as:

```
1/5/8     18      31.2                0     1847550953       13013135          5598945               3.00e-01
1/5/9     18      34.2                0     1748942583       6401826          5598945               3.00e-01
1/5/10     18      34.6                0     1847550953       13013135          5598945               3.00e-01
1/5/11     18      34.4                0     1847550953       13013135          5598945               3.00e-01
```

The data comes in this format but the numbers may be different.  What I'm trying to do is have a script that grabs what is in the 3rd column so in this example the 31.2, 34.2, 34.6 and 34.4 then takes those numbers, gives me their average by adding them up and dividing by 4 and then displaying the result in a different textarea box.

I'm also wondering if it can be done in a single script or does it need two scripts.  One to parse then the other to calculate and display the average in a textarea.

Comment: Are there really newlines between each row? (suggest code formatting for clarity)

Comment: No.  It's always 4 lines and formatted the same.  Just that need the third row parsed and then taking the numbers, adding them up and dividing by 4 and displaying the result in a textarea field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` the lines and `map` to match the third column. Then you can find the average and put the result in another textarea:

```js
const input = `1/5/8     18      31.2                0     1847550953       13013135          5598945               3.00e-01
1/5/9     18      34.2                0     1748942583       6401826          5598945               3.00e-01
1/5/10     18      34.6                0     1847550953       13013135          5598945               3.00e-01
1/5/11     18      34.4                0     1847550953       13013135          5598945               3.00e-01`;
const thirdRowMatches = input.split('\n')
  .map(line => line.split(/ +/)[2])
const avg = thirdRowMatches.reduce((a, str) => a + Number(str), 0) / thirdRowMatches.length;
document.querySelector('#textarea2').value = avg;
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>
```

Comment: That regex is nasty... What about just split on whitespace?

Comment: That works perfectly.  The only issue I'm running I to is changing it to a user input.

I added a text area:

     <textarea id="input"></textarea>

Then changed the first line of the script to:

     const = document.getElementById('#input').value;

But I end up with a syntax error of the element not be null

Comment: @Michael That sounds like a completely different issue from what you asked initially (and if you get a syntax error, that's not a ReferenceError - it shouldn't be complaining about `null`)

Comment: Actually I was Able to figure it out.  It's working perfectly now.  Thank you very much.